# How to handle async data in ngOnInit (routing with parameter) Angular 4

Tags: c#, angular, sql-server-2014-express, asp.net-core-1.1

I am trying to load data from my web api controller. 
Currently I am using my API service which I call from the ngOnInit function of the component.
But, nothing return in the view because it's an asynchronous data

Web api controller

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<UserModel> GetUserById(int id)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 200;
        try
        {
            _context = new AuthentificationDbContext();
            UserModel user = await _context.User.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.id == id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
              return (user);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }
    }
```

userService.ts

```
getUserId(id: number) : Observable<User>{
    return this.http.get(this.url + 'userApi/GetUserById/?id=' + id)
        .map(res => <User>res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

app.routing.ts

```
{ path: 'user/:id', component: UserComponent}
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,{ 
                                            enableTracing:true});
export const routedComponents = [UserComponent];
```

user.component.ts

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
private user: User;
constructor(private userService: UserService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {  
           this.route.paramMap
                    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
                        this.userService.getUserId(+params.get('id')))
                    .subscribe((user: User) => {
                        this.user = user;
                    });

    }

}
```

user.cshtml

```
<div *ngIf="user">{{ user.name}}</div>
```

But, when I tried with that example, that's work because not asynchronous

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
export class User {
constructor(public id: number, public name: string) { }
}
let Users = [
new User(11, 'Mr. Nice'),
new User(12, 'Narco')
];
let usersPromise = Promise.resolve(Users);
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
constructor( @Inject(Http) public http: Http) { }

    getUserId(id: number | string) {
        return usersPromise
            .then(users => users.find(user => user.id === +id));
    }

}
```

My question : how to load async data in ngOnInit? 
I used by promise also, but doesn't work

Comment: .subscribe((user: User) => {
                        this.user = user; here did you try console.log(this.user) to check what data you have received?

Comment: Please add the code that shows how you use `user` in the view. Even if your code is async, it still sets `this.user` (if `this.userService.getUserId(+params.get('id'))` is valid code and eventually a response arrives. Your code might break if you depend on the result being available immediately, but that's hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: Yes, I'm using by console.log(this.user) but the problem is about async data in web api controller. I tried with another example, that's work  
    export class User { constructor(public id: number, public name: string) 
   { }
   let Users = [ new User(11, 'Mr. Nice'), new User(12, 'Narco')];
   let usersPromise = Promise.resolve(Users);  getUserId(id: number | 
   string) { return usersPromise.then(users => users.find(user => 
   user.id=== +id)); } }

Comment: The code in the view    <div *ngIf="user"> <h3>{{ user.name}}</h3> </div>

Comment: Code in comments is quite hard to read, please edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: That's ok, now the question has updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can resolve my problem (it's related to routing) :
my code just need to insert this :

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

at the top of the 'head' section.

---

And to insert in constructor from app.component.ts, this methode:

```
click() {
    this.router.navigate(['', { foo: 'bar' }]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
{{user.view}}
```

in the components template, you'll get an error, because `user` isn't available immediately.

```
{{user?.view}}
```

(safe-nativation operator) avoids this error by not throwing an exception when `user` is null.

Comment: Thanks Günter, I know the problem is with user isn't available immediately. My question is how to load async data in ngOnInit?

Comment: Your code is already loading data async. Have you even tried my suggestion? Have you checked if you get an error?

Comment: I tried with your suggestion, but doesn't work
I execute my code with debugger and I put a stop, but the debugger does not execute the function in web api controller, just execute userService.ts

Comment: What exactly is "the function"?

Comment: public async Task<UserModel> GetUserById(int id)

Comment: Please, can you give me an example explain how to get async data in ngOnInit from web api controller

Comment: I don't know what you ask for. There is no difference whether you try to get async data it in `ngOnInit()` or elsewhere. Perhaps your async code is invalid, but the problem is not related to `ngOnInit`

Comment: Ok, thanks  Günter, I think the problem is related to routing with parameters because I tried by many examples without parameters and no problem.
I'm beginner in angular 4 and there is my first example from routing with parameter, just time and I will resolve it.